# How to make work SqlQuery<> method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use entity framework 6 in my project.

I use SqlQuery method of the Database class to get some string value from table.

Here is the code:

```
string name = "Dana";

context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT DisplayName FROM Users WHERE Username = name ", name).ToList();
```

But it seems that I use **name** variable inside `SqlQuery` method wrong.

Any idea what should I fix in my `SqlQuery` method string to query work properly?

Comment: use `name = @name` in your query

Comment: `context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT DisplayName FROM Users WHERE Username = @p0", name).ToList();`

Comment: @MohitShrivastava - No, that is the last thing that anyone should ever write and is bad advice even in a comment. This will lead to possible errors and leaves the code vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT DisplayName FROM Users WHERE Username = @p0", name).ToList();
```

> Any parameter values you supply will automatically be converted to a DbParameter.

See [Database.SqlQuery Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery%28System.Type,System.String,System.Object[]%29)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify that `name` is a parameter. Add `@` before it:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT DisplayName FROM Users WHERE Username = @p0", name).ToList();
```

If you want to name the parameters then use `SqlParameter` class:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(
    "SELECT DisplayName FROM Users WHERE Username = @name", 
    new SqlParameter("@name", name)
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT DisplayName FROM Users WHERE Username = @name ", 
                new SqlParameter("@name", name)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put `@` before your name parameter. Also you shouldnt just pass a string into the method. its better if you use `SqlParameter` to prevent any Sql Injection

```
string name = "Dana";
SqlParameter paramName = new SqlParameter("name", name );
context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT DisplayName FROM Users WHERE Username = @name ", paramName ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use it something like this way:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(
    "SELECT DisplayName FROM Users WHERE Username = @name",
    new SqlParameter("name", name)
).ToList();
```